# Spring Boot, JPA, @Query, Sybase stored procedure

Tags: java, spring-boot, sybase

Trying to make a Sybase stored procedure call using JPA @Query.  I was following the info presented here, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures, as a guideline, even though the info is for MySQL and named parameters.  I know the stored procedure works, as I can execute it using a client, DBVis.  I also know the values to the stored procedure are correct, as I've turned on hibernate logging and I always see the following snippet before each call :

```
2020-12-30 13:51:07 TRACE o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [pub_req_t]
2020-12-30 13:51:07 TRACE o.h.t.d.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [1]
```

The @Query looks like the following :

```
@Query(value = "call rp_surrogate(?1, ?2);", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV1(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );
```

The stored procedure declaration is :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.rp_surrogate (
    @surrtype       char(32),
    @newsurr        domn_num_id    output
)
as begin
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I pass into the ?2 (output) parameter, as it's ignored anyway.  I've tried both jconn4, version 7.0, and jtds, version 1.3.1, JDBC drivers...both produce the same exception :

- jconn4 - Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.
- jtds - Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

Runtime Stack :

- Spring Boot 2.2.8
- Java 1.8
- Sybase ASE 15

I've tried using @Modifying annotation in conjunction with @Trasactional : Thinking the JPA would perhaps utilize @P0 as rowsUpdated or a status code for the stored procedure...Nope.

```
@Modifying
@Query(value = "call rp_surrogate(?1, ?2);", nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
int getSurrogateByQueryV1(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );

Results in : Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@p0'.
```

Also, tried 4 variations on the @Query, all return the same exception...Some with a semi-colon, some with a call.

```
@Query(value = "call rp_surrogate(?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV1(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );

Results in : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

@Query(value = "call rp_surrogate(?1, ?2);", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV2(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );

Results in : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

@Query(value = "rp_surrogate(?1, ?2);", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV3(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );

Results in : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.

@Query(value = "rp_surrogate(?1, ?2)", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV4(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );

Results in : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
```

About the only thing I can report that works is the following, which works, but we'd like to have a clean/lean version using @Query, since some of these procedures we need to call are fairly large in parameters.

```
@Override
public int getSurrogateByType(String typeSurrogate) {
    EntityManager em = secondaryEntityManager.getObject().createEntityManager();

    StoredProcedureQuery query = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("rp_surrogate");
    // JDBC : The jconn and jtDS drivers do NOT understand named parameters...we
    // MUST use positional...
    //query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("surrtype",     String.class,     ParameterMode.IN    );
    //query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("newsurr",     Long.class,     ParameterMode.OUT    );
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class,     ParameterMode.IN);
    query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, Integer.class,    ParameterMode.OUT);
    getLog().error("getSurrogateByType() - Surrogate Type [{}]", typeSurrogate);
    query.setParameter(1, typeSurrogate);

    try {
        query.execute();
    } catch (Exception ltheXcp) {
        getLog().error("{}() - process failure, with exception(s) : ", this.getClass().getSimpleName(), ltheXcp);
        ltheXcp.printStackTrace();
        throw ltheXcp;
    }

    Integer commentCount = (Integer) query.getOutputParameterValue(2);
    return commentCount.intValue();

}
```

Does anyone know how to make such a call with a Sybase driver and @Query?

Comment: can you make queries direct in Sybase? Have you tried what works there? I always had errors with sybase because it expected the owner name for example dbo.rp_surrogate()

Comment: Which dialect was configured in the application?

Comment: Yup, we can use the JPA Repository and Entities to fetch records from tables and such.  Dialect is org.hibernate.dialect.SybaseDialect.

Comment: Have you tried `@Procedure` like explained [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures) if it makes any difference?

Answer (score 0):

Sybase native query won't support "Call"  and use "exec"

```
@Query(value = "exec rp_surrogate  ?1, ?2 ", nativeQuery = true)
int getSurrogateByQueryV1(String surrtype, Integer newsurr );
```